Where do I want to see the data source's file location for the Great Expectations?
Basically, I want to check on the great expectations that I've set for my bootcamp project.
I run the code below:
# Give a name to a Datasource. This name must be unique between Datasources.
datasource_name = 'supermarketSales'
datasource = context.sources.add_pandas(datasource_name)

# Give a name to a data asset
asset_name = 'sales of supermarket'
path_to_data = 'P2M3_Daffa_Darwin_data_clean.csv'
asset = datasource.add_csv_asset(asset_name, filepath_or_buffer=path_to_data)

# Build batch request
batch_request = asset.build_batch_request()

Then the output is like this:
DataContextError: Can not write the fluent datasource supermarketSales because a datasource of that name already exists in the data context.

Although, I've done it in my bootcamp and graduated, then I want to check again if it still works or not.
